# About json_serializable memory

Tags: flutter, dart

I examined the model we created with Json serializable. When we look at the example.g.dart, the methods created are global methods. In other words, global variables and methods enter ram at compile time and are not deleted from memory. The difference here is part, part-of and private. Does this have an effect on memory? Are these methods deleted?